# Single domain for Azure Blob and Servcice App

Tags: azure, service, blob

I have a blog on WordPress, which I have converted into ASP.NET Core. I am using Azure Service App. As it's a blog, so it has a lot of images, around 4GB of images. For now, I have placed these images in the wwwroot folder. Now I want to transfer them to Blob storage.

But problem is that, when I add images in Blob, I get a different link. I have used Azure CDN and have tried custom domain. But here the issue comes is:

1. My Service App is running at www..com
2. I am able to redirect my Blob CDN to images..com .... I have added it in the DNS record

But what I want is to use the same domain www..com for both Blob and Service App, which I tried my best but couldn't achieve. The main reason is I couldn't add multiple CNAME for www.

Why I can't change the link, coz it will affect my blog's SEO, so I can't take that risk. Need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> what I want is to use the same domain www..com for both Blob and Service App

This is not possible you can use sub-domain on your CDN Endpoint and main domain on service app.

1. Create CDN.
2. Add custom sub-domain on CDN Endpoints. For example :- if your domain [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) then you can use cdn.abc.com, image.abc.com, photo.abc.com etc.

[image]

More information about [Add Cutom Domain on CDN read these Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain?tabs=azure-dns%2Cazure-portal%2Cazure-portal-cleanup#add-a-custom-domain-to-your-cdn-endpoint).

SO thread on same issue [It is **not** possible to provision same domain for different service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697863/is-it-possible-to-provision-the-same-domain-name-on-multiple-azure-websites)